# Conjugation of a direct product

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $H \times K \leq G = A\times B$ and let $g\in G$. Is it true that $g( H\times K)g^{-1} = gHg^{-1} \times gKg^{-1}$ holds in general?

Comment: The fact that $G = A \times B$ is irrelevant and distracting. You could just delete "$=A \times B$", and the answer would still be yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$g(H\times K)g^{-1}=g\{(h, k)\in H\times K\}g^{-1}=\{g(h, k)g^{-1}|(h,k)\in H\times K\}=\{(ghg^{-1}, gkg^{-1})|(h, k)\in H\times K\}=gHg^{-1}\times gK^{-1} $$

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that, in this answer as well as the question, elements $h\in H$ (or $k\in K$) are tacitly identified with elements $(h,1)$ (or $(1,k)$) of $G$, so that $ghg^{-1}$ (or $gkg^{-1}$) makes sense.